# Android 6.0 - Cannot create directory on SD card

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-sdcard

I have a problem creating directory on SD card.

**AndroidManifest.xml** contains neccessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application...
```

Also for Android 6.0 I ask these permissions at runtime:

```
int permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
int permissionCheck2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
if (permissionCheck1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || permissionCheck2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_READWRITE_STORAGE);
} else {
    init();
}
```

and waiting for results:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_READWRITE_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                init();
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Read / Write storage permissions required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

My application determines two available storages:

internal - **/storage/emulated/0**

and external (removable SD card) - **/storage/6052-CD5B**

I create folders using

```
new File(parentDirectory, newDirectoryName).mkdirs();
```

Results:

I can create folder inside **/storage/emulated/0**.

I can create folder inside **/storage/6052-CD5B/Android/data/myapp** (this is my application folder).

But I can't create folder in **/storage/6052-CD5B** outside my application folder, e.g. images folder **/storage/6052-CD5B/DCIM**.

It seems that granted permissions give me access only to application-specific folder. Is it so? If not, how can I finally get write access to other SD card folders?

Comment: Have you tried checking on phone in App's settings if the Permissions are really granted? In 6.0 I had to give writer external storage permissions manually, when I was installing the App through ADB (USB).

Comment: Access to your app's directory does not require explicit permissions any more: ["*Starting in API level 19, this permission is not required to read/write files in your application-specific directories returned by getExternalFilesDir(String) and getExternalCacheDir().*"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) So it looks like the requested permissions have not actually been granted.

Comment: @DavidK, I've checked this, and Application Settings say that both permissions "Read SD card" and "Write SD card" are granted.

Comment: @dhke, indeed, my app's directory is always accessible for reading and writing, regardless of permissions. I've found an interesting article, explaining External Storage Permissions in Android: https://possiblemobile.com/2014/03/android-external-storage/ . According to this article, modern versions of Android manage external storage using FUSE. SD card is a secondary external storage, and, again according to the article, top-level directories and other applications' directories are never writable by my application. Bad thing  that I don't know what to do with this.